# Distributional Fourier transform of $F(x) = \log(-i(x+ia))$

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

Define a function $F: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$
$$F(x) = \log(-i(x+ia)),$$
where $a=0^+$ is a regulator, and the logarithm is always in the principal branch.

$F$ is a tempered distribution: for any $g\in \mathcal S(\mathbb R)$,
$$\langle F,g \rangle = \lim_{a\to0^+} \int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x) g(x) \: dx$$
is well-defined and $g\mapsto \langle F,g \rangle$ is continuous. (To prove this, we adopt the method in [log|x| is a tempered distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3661815/logx-is-a-tempered-distribution))

**Question**: What is the Fourier transform
$$\hat F(k) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x) e^{-ikx} dx$$
of $F$?

Remark: Differentiation gives $F'(x) = \frac{1}{x+ia}$. This is a well-known distribution whose Fourier transform is $\widehat{F'}(k) = -2\pi i \Theta(k)$, where $\Theta$ is the Heaviside function. Hence, using the property $\widehat{F'}(k) = ik\widehat F(k)$, we have
$$\widehat F(k) = -\frac{2\pi}{k} \Theta(k) + C\delta(k),$$
where $C$ is a constant. Hence, the problem reduces to determine $C$.

Comment: There is also a term $C\delta(k),$ where $C$ is some constant.

Comment: @md2perpe I think you mean the last equation. Sure, and it is my question to determine $C$.